# Finding User Agents and IPs which make more than 10 req/s in access logs

Tags: apache, logging, awk, grep, access-log

I would like to find IP addresses and user agents that have made more than 10 server requests per second. Help me, please. How can I do this? Maybe with awk, grep?

Here's a typical lines from my Access Log:

```
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-v-korpuse-pechki-honda-cr-v-200-pr-1019 HTTP/1.0" 200 387654 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-v-salone-honda-cr-v-2002-2006-pr-1018 HTTP/1.0" 200 387484 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-naruzhnogo-vozduha-defekt-honda-pr-12550 HTTP/1.0" 200 387484 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/klapan-otopitelya-benzin-honda-cr-v-2002-2006-797-pr-1006 HTTP/1.0" 200 387449 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/kronshtejn-radiatora-kondicionera-pravyj-honda-cr-pr-1008 HTTP/1.0" 200 387996 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/provodka-pechki-honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-pr-12228 HTTP/1.0" 200 386676 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-v-korpuse-pechki-honda-cr-v-200-pr-1019 HTTP/1.0" 200 387654 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-v-salone-honda-cr-v-2002-2006-pr-1018 HTTP/1.0" 200 387484 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-naruzhnogo-vozduha-defekt-honda-pr-12550 HTTP/1.0" 200 387484 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/klapan-otopitelya-benzin-honda-cr-v-2002-2006-797-pr-1006 HTTP/1.0" 200 387449 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/kronshtejn-radiatora-kondicionera-pravyj-honda-cr-pr-1008 HTTP/1.0" 200 387996 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/provodka-pechki-honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-pr-12228 HTTP/1.0" 200 386676 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:51 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/rozshiryuvalnij-klapan-kondicionera-honda-cr-v-2-2-pr-11867 HTTP/1.0" 200 387227 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:55 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/servoprivod-zaslonki-pechki-pravyj1-honda-cr-v-200-pr-1001 HTTP/1.0" 200 387750 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:24:41 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-77970s9ab812m1-honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-pr-12578 HTTP/1.0" 200 386162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:24:45 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-77970s9ac812m1-honda-cr-v-2-2002-200-pr-12577 HTTP/1.0" 200 386159 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:24:53 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-77970scag911m1-honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-pr-12575 HTTP/1.0" 200 386141 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:25:00 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-perednij-levyj-77940s9an810-honda-cr-pr-12557 HTTP/1.0" 200 386548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
95.216.137.119 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:25:06 +0200] "POST /index.php?route=api/login HTTP/1.0" 200 190 "-" "-"
95.216.137.119 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:25:07 +0200] "GET /index.php?route=api/oneboxsync/getOrderValue/&token=95ghttSKDUuykyhc4fY4tcDCuAmpZxrQ&api_token= HTTP/1.0" 200 216719 "-" "-"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:25:09 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-perednij-levyj-honda-cr-v-2002-2006-pr-992 HTTP/1.0" 200 386813 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:25:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-perednij-pravyj-77930s9an810-honda-cr-pr-12574 HTTP/1.0" 200 386777 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
```

For finding info about UA's I'm running this: (Gives me the amount of hits each unique UA has)

```
awk -F\" '{print $6}' /www/logs/www.example.com-access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -fr
```

What can I do differently to make these commands show me only IPs, from which was made , more than 10 requests per second?

If there are some IP from which was made 10 and more requests to the server, I want to find it in my log.
https://prnt.sc/1zKKp6tXx0UZ - this is 10 request per second from the same IP (176.9.50.244), so it mast be catched with the command and print to screen

In this case (corresponding to the new set of input data) the output must be like this - must be printed just one IP

```
176.9.50.244
```

When counting the number of reqs/sec, it must count all lines with the same timestamp and the same IP. Lets forget about UA, and try to focus on IP.
I use UA is for additional information only.

Comment: your logs is from surveillance camera. What/who are you searching there?

Comment: please update the question with sample data including a couple IPs ... one with <200 req/s and one with >=200 req/s; then update the question to include the expected output (corresponding to the nw set of inputs); actually, if the '200' is a count of the number of lines then provide a sample set of data let's say, where the cutoff is 5 lines (ie, replace '200' with '5')

Comment: Yes, agreed. On your timestamp `[28/Jan/2023:03:24:41 +0200]` is the `+200` the count or a GMT offset? Good luck.

Comment: i have updated the question with sample data including a couple IPs one with >=10 req/s and other with < 10 req/s, and changed the title from ">200" to > ">10"

Comment: please update the question to include the expected output (corresponding to the new set of input data)

Comment: I assume `03:26:14` and `03:26:19` are the same minute and not second.

Comment: when counting the number of reqs/sec must all lines with the same timestamp have not only the same IP but also the same UA? or can a series of lines (w/ same timestamp; w/ same IP) have different UAs?

Comment: following up on Cyrus' comment ... please confirm if you're looking for requests ***per minute*** or requests ***per second***; current logs appear to show mulitiple requests *per minute*

Comment: We can't test a possible solution with only sample input, you need to provide the expected output given that input too.

Comment: @cyrus thanks, i have changed an input data and have made a new screenshot, so now it  matches to seconds

Comment: @markp-fuso
When counting the number of reqs/sec, it must count all lines with the same timestamp and the same IP. Lets forget about UA, and try to focus on IP.

Comment: So you have a combination of IP and timestamp. One way could be to concatenate those two to make a key in an array in AWK, then add +1 for this key.  Like `c[ip + timestamp] ++`  Do for every line. At the end, loop over keys and print where count >=10.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.  One is below.  Please mark as correct or add comment and I will address this further.

```
Mac_3.2.57$cat input.txt | awk '{print "IP=" $1 " time=" $4,$5}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{if($1>10){print $0}}'
  12 IP=176.9.50.244 time=[28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200]
Mac_3.2.57$cat input.txt
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-v-korpuse-pechki-honda-cr-v-200-pr-1019 HTTP/1.0" 200 387654 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-v-salone-honda-cr-v-2002-2006-pr-1018 HTTP/1.0" 200 387484 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-naruzhnogo-vozduha-defekt-honda-pr-12550 HTTP/1.0" 200 387484 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/klapan-otopitelya-benzin-honda-cr-v-2002-2006-797-pr-1006 HTTP/1.0" 200 387449 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/kronshtejn-radiatora-kondicionera-pravyj-honda-cr-pr-1008 HTTP/1.0" 200 387996 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/provodka-pechki-honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-pr-12228 HTTP/1.0" 200 386676 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-v-korpuse-pechki-honda-cr-v-200-pr-1019 HTTP/1.0" 200 387654 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-v-salone-honda-cr-v-2002-2006-pr-1018 HTTP/1.0" 200 387484 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-naruzhnogo-vozduha-defekt-honda-pr-12550 HTTP/1.0" 200 387484 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/klapan-otopitelya-benzin-honda-cr-v-2002-2006-797-pr-1006 HTTP/1.0" 200 387449 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/kronshtejn-radiatora-kondicionera-pravyj-honda-cr-pr-1008 HTTP/1.0" 200 387996 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/provodka-pechki-honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-pr-12228 HTTP/1.0" 200 386676 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:51 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/rozshiryuvalnij-klapan-kondicionera-honda-cr-v-2-2-pr-11867 HTTP/1.0" 200 387227 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:55 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/servoprivod-zaslonki-pechki-pravyj1-honda-cr-v-200-pr-1001 HTTP/1.0" 200 387750 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:24:41 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-77970s9ab812m1-honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-pr-12578 HTTP/1.0" 200 386162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:24:45 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-77970s9ac812m1-honda-cr-v-2-2002-200-pr-12577 HTTP/1.0" 200 386159 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:24:53 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-77970scag911m1-honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-pr-12575 HTTP/1.0" 200 386141 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:25:00 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-perednij-levyj-77940s9an810-honda-cr-pr-12557 HTTP/1.0" 200 386548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
95.216.137.119 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:25:06 +0200] "POST /index.php?route=api/login HTTP/1.0" 200 190 "-" "-"
95.216.137.119 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:25:07 +0200] "GET /index.php?route=api/oneboxsync/getOrderValue/&token=95ghttSKDUuykyhc4fY4tcDCuAmpZxrQ&api_token= HTTP/1.0" 200 216719 "-" "-"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:25:09 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-perednij-levyj-honda-cr-v-2002-2006-pr-992 HTTP/1.0" 200 386813 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:25:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-perednij-pravyj-77930s9an810-honda-cr-pr-12574 HTTP/1.0" 200 386777 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
Mac_3.2.57$
```

Comment: it prints IPs and uniq timestamps, but I need only IPs, from which was made , more than 10 requests per second

Answer (score 1):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v limit=10 '                       # set awk variable "limit" to number of matches per second
    { ip_ts[$1 FS $4]++ }               # keep count of how many times we see this ip/timestamp combo
END { for (i in ip_ts)                  # loop through all ip/timestamp indices and ...
          if (ip_ts[i] >= limit) {      # if the count >= "limit" then ...
             split(i,a)                 # split the ip/timestamp pair (on FS) and ...
             print a[1]                 # print the ip
          }
    }
' access.log
```

Adding some variation to the input file:

```
$ cat access.log
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-v-korpuse-pechki-honda-cr-v-200-pr-1019 HTTP/1.0" 200 387654 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-v-salone-honda-cr-v-2002-2006-pr-1018 HTTP/1.0" 200 387484 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-naruzhnogo-vozduha-defekt-honda-pr-12550 HTTP/1.0" 200 387484 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/klapan-otopitelya-benzin-honda-cr-v-2002-2006-797-pr-1006 HTTP/1.0" 200 387449 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/kronshtejn-radiatora-kondicionera-pravyj-honda-cr-pr-1008 HTTP/1.0" 200 387996 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/provodka-pechki-honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-pr-12228 HTTP/1.0" 200 386676 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-v-korpuse-pechki-honda-cr-v-200-pr-1019 HTTP/1.0" 200 387654 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-v-salone-honda-cr-v-2002-2006-pr-1018 HTTP/1.0" 200 387484 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/datchik-temperatury-naruzhnogo-vozduha-defekt-honda-pr-12550 HTTP/1.0" 200 387484 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/klapan-otopitelya-benzin-honda-cr-v-2002-2006-797-pr-1006 HTTP/1.0" 200 387449 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/kronshtejn-radiatora-kondicionera-pravyj-honda-cr-pr-1008 HTTP/1.0" 200 387996 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/provodka-pechki-honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-pr-12228 HTTP/1.0" 200 386676 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
223.1.37.179 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:51 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/rozshiryuvalnij-klapan-kondicionera-honda-cr-v-2-2-pr-11867 HTTP/1.0" 200 387227 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
223.1.37.179 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:51 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-obogreva-i-klimata-54/servoprivod-zaslonki-pechki-pravyj1-honda-cr-v-200-pr-1001 HTTP/1.0" 200 387750 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
223.1.37.179 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:51 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-77970s9ab812m1-honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-pr-12578 HTTP/1.0" 200 386162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
223.1.37.179 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:26:51 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-77970s9ac812m1-honda-cr-v-2-2002-200-pr-12577 HTTP/1.0" 200 386159 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:34:53 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-77970scag911m1-honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-pr-12575 HTTP/1.0" 200 386141 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:34.53 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-perednij-levyj-77940s9an810-honda-cr-pr-12557 HTTP/1.0" 200 386548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
95.216.137.119 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:25:06 +0200] "POST /index.php?route=api/login HTTP/1.0" 200 190 "-" "-"
95.216.137.119 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:25:07 +0200] "GET /index.php?route=api/oneboxsync/getOrderValue/&token=95ghttSKDUuykyhc4fY4tcDCuAmpZxrQ&api_token= HTTP/1.0" 200 216719 "-" "-"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:25:09 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-perednij-levyj-honda-cr-v-2002-2006-pr-992 HTTP/1.0" 200 386813 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
176.9.50.244 - - [28/Jan/2023:03:25:14 +0200] "GET /honda-1/honda-cr-v-2-2002-2006-12/sistema-bezopasnosti-52/datchik-udara-perednij-pravyj-77930s9an810-honda-cr-pr-12574 HTTP/1.0" 200 386777 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MegaIndex.ru/2.0; +http://megaindex.com/crawler)"
```

For `limit=10` this generates:

```
176.9.50.244
```

For `limit=4` this generates:

```
176.9.50.244
223.1.37.179
```

For `limit=2` this generates:

```
176.9.50.244                  
176.9.50.244
223.1.37.179
```

**NOTES:**

- for the 3rd set of output `176.9.50.244` shows up twice; it's not clear from OP's description if we should only show an ip once in the final output, or once for each unique set of timestamps that match the criteria
- order of the output lines is not guaranteed; if output order is important OP can pipe the results to `sort` or add code to have `awk` sort the data before printing to stdout

Comment: I try to run your command, but it make an error
`[root@vm3943175 detail]# awk -v limit=10 '{ ip_ts[$1 FS $4]++ } END { for (i in ip_ts) if (ip_ts[i] >= limit) { split(i,a) print a[1] } }' jap.kiev.ua.access.log

awk: cmd. line:1: { ip_ts[$1 FS $4]++ } END { for (i in ip_ts) if (ip_ts[i] >= limit) { split(i,a) print a[1] } }
awk: cmd. line:1:   ^ syntax error `
[link]https://prnt.sc/fPg9FKOy6RSi

Comment: @shurc running as a multi-line command (as in the answer) ... no errors; if you're trying to run it as a `'one-liner'` then you have to take care to add semicolons to separate commands ... in this case you need a semicolon between the `split()` and `print` => `{ split(i,a); print a[1] )`

Comment: Is there a way to print the number of requests next to each IP? Like this `176.9.50.244 -> 4; 
223.1.37.179 -> 10`

Comment: `print a[i] " -> " ip_ts[i]`